# Typhoon 1.7.2: XML Injection - Unable to resolve class

Tags: objective-c, swift, typhoon

Disclaimer: I know that this is a pretty old version of Typhoon, but I'm trying to add a Swift class to an existing Objective-C codebase, and I'm curious if this could work (in theory, I think it should).

I have the following Swift Cocoa class:

```
import Cocoa

public class MyClass: NSObject {

}
```

I would like to use it as a dependency in an Objective-C class:

```
@interface DependentClass()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MyClass *myClass;

@end

- (instancetype)initWithMyClass:(MyClass *)aClass {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myClass = aClass;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my XML configuration, I register the component, and the dependent class:

```
<component class='MyClass' key='myClass' scope='singleton'>
</component>

<component class='DependentClass' key='dependentClass' scope='singleton'>
    <initializer selector='initWithMyClass:'>
            <argument parameterName='myClass' ref='myClass'/>
    </initializer>
</component>
```

When I launch the application, it crashes while resolving myClass:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Class 'MyClass' can't be
>   resolved.'

Is there a way to make it work? As far as I know the only thing I have to do is make `MyClass` an `NSObject` subclass (either my sublassing, or using @objc).

Comment: This would work in theory, but the name of the Swift class is likely to be auto-namespaced to app/frameworkname.ClassName. I forget the exact fomat, but you could test that at runtime using NSStringFromClass(MyClass.self) ?

Comment: Wow, you're right, I completely forgot about the module namespace. I've added the namespace to the XML, and now it works. Thanks! If you write it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted!

Comment: Added (very brief) answer as requested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but the name of the Swift class will be be auto-namespaced to app/frameworkname.ClassName.

You could test that at runtime using `NSStringFromClass(MyClass.self)`